# Open dev tools for html in TextDocumentContentProvider

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to open the devtools for a html preview document?

I know you can do it for a electron webview component.
So far I can see, html preview is also rendered in an electron webview.
But I can't get a handle to the webview to open the devtools like this

> webview.openDevTools()

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer here

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/12818

Modify your keybindings like so and you should be able to bring up dev tools for the preview (when it's visible/running)

```
{
   "key": "shift+cmd+j",
   "command": "_webview.openDevTools" 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening the webview is now an official developer command.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/44068

Control-shift-p or command-shift-p to access to command prompt.

[image]